# Getting the PK of a record before being saved on the database sqlserver and C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

Good day guys,

I am creating a system for saving details of a user, i have attributes (UserID(pk-Auto),name,surname,disability(FK)..

I have 3 tables, being

- **user** ( UserID(pk), Name, surname, disability(fk) )
- **disability** ( DisabilityID(pk), Disability(YES/NO) )
- **disabilitype** ( DisabilityTypeID(PK), disabilityID(fk), UserID(fk), disabilityName )

The disability have an option of yes/now(with the id for yes being 1 and 2 for no), if the user clicks yes the system must be able to save data on disabilityType and retrieve the PK of user of which it is unknown because the user details will saved afer the if statement of the disability attribute

Comment: So there is nothing that identifies a user? If you have two John Miller, you don't know which record belongs to which of the two? Usually a user would have a natural ID, e.g. a login name, an insurance number, a passport number, whatever, you would store with the data. Shouldn't this be the same in your system?

Comment: And a user has exactly one disability? And a disablity type is again a user with a disability? In short: the data model seems wrong.

Comment: With this model there is no need to have IDnumber, we are going to have multiple john miller with different email,phone and company name. so i will use the primary key to identify users; leave the model alone and focus on the question at hand not the model(design), what i want is the mechanism on how to catch the identifier (userID) that is a primary key

Comment: Okay, you didn't show those other user columns. Or is it tables? However, as you are able to identify the record from its data as you say, it's very easy to get the id. E.g.: `insert into user values ('John', 'Miller', 128)`, then `select userid from user where name = 'John' and surname = 'Miller' and disability = 128`.

Comment: i am going to edit my post because someone deleted my code so that it can be clearer on what i was doing and what kind of solution i am looking for, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

if you mean you want the id of the next entered row before save it you can get it by making a trick first get the last entered id.for example if you have table called `user` and the `primary key` is `Id` you can select last entered `id` by this query `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('user')` and then the `next id` is the `output` value `+1`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use @@Identity to get at the id that was generated by the statement. So when you insert into the User table add an out parameter that returns the @@Identity, then use that value to save int the disabilitype table accordingly.

```
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into User ... //Brevity 

        RETURN @@IDENTITY
        ", cn)) {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter returnValue = new SqlParameter();
            returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(returnValue);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```